# IP address for deployed Meteor app (meteor.com)?

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor app I've deployed to meteor.com.  It's up and running fine meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com, however I need to adjust firewall rules so servers can see it.

Does it have a static IP, and if so how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

```
ping yourappname.meteor.com
```

Note that the IP is not guaranteed to be static, so it might change from time to time.